# node->pointer = pointer vs node->pointer using memcpy

Tags: c, pointers, memory, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is my structure:

```
typedef struct s_list
{
    void *content;
    size_t content_size;
    struct s_list *next;
}   t_list;
```

I'm trying to create a function to create a new node:

```
t_list *lstnew(void const *content, size_t content_size);
```

My question is why the following differ in results:

Why does the following code works perfectly:

```
node->content = memcpy(node->content, content, content_size);
```

When the following does not:

```
node->content = content;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Probably because `memcpy` copies all of the data, while the assignment only copies the *pointer*.

Comment: The assignement is not necessary, `node->content = memcpy(node->content, content, content_size);` is equivalent to `memcpy(node->content, content, content_size);`. Now it should be more clear to you why the `memcpy` way works and the `node->content = content;` does not work.

Comment: By the way, if you allocated memory using e.g. `malloc` and made `node->content` point to that memory, you will have a memory leak with `node->content = content`, as you lose the original pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content` contains just the address of where your data is stored in memory.

With `node->content = content` you don't copy any data. All you do is setting `node->content` to the memory address that's in `content`.

After that `node->content` and `content` **both point to the same memory/data**. If that memory is changed or even freed, your `node` will point to changed or freed memory too.

To make sure that your `node` has a private copy of the `content` (that you pass in `listnew()`), you must use `memcpy()`. Then the rest of your program can change/free the original `content` without affecting `node->content`.

EDIT: I assume that you're aware that you must first allocate memory and assign its address to `node->content` before using `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment :

```
node->content = content;
```

just makes pointer `node->content` point at the same place where pointer `content` does, without copying anything.

However,

```
memcpy(node->content, content, content_size);
```

actually ***copies*** the contents of the place where pointer `content` points to the place where pointer `node->content` points.